# Laravel Mail: Undifine variable $data

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My Controller generates this data array:

```
Array
(
    [bothweek] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2014-10-26
            [1] => 2014-10-19
        )

    [projects] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [day_name] => Wednesday
                    [project_date] => 2014-10-22
                    [invoiced_date] => 2014-10-31
                    [week_end_day] => 2014-10-26
                    [user_name] => John
                 )
        )
)
```

But when i try to send this to mail blade, it not recognize this array, can someone please give me a solution, thank you,

```
Mail::send('project.mail', $data, function ($message) {
    $message->from('email', 'ABC');

    $message->to('send');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `$data` to be accessible in you view file `project.mail` you need to use `['data' => $data]` as the second argument, otherwise you will get two variables, `$bothweek` and `$projects`.

```
Mail::send('project.mail', ['data' => $data], function ($message) {
    ...
});
```